# SharePoint 2019 My site not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, 2019

We have come across a strange issue with mysite creation on a SharePoint 2019 on-prem deployment where in mysites are not creating for the users

My site gives the following error

**We're sorry. Something went wrong with your My Site setup.
Please try again later or contact your help desk.**

****Event ID 8100 on event viewer,****

Mysite provisioning failed for user:[i:0#.w|domain\user] with correlationid:[9583edc9-332f-4001-8e6d-298df66ec7d4] on retry attempt:[0] on queue type:[]. Error:[SiteProvisioningException: ExceptionType: SelfServiceSiteCreate InnerException: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.0x80004005
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.AddInternal(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteProvisioning.SiteProvisioningManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteProvisioning.SiteProvisioningException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteProvisioning.SiteProvisioningException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

** Error in ULS logs**

Site creation failure for user 'UserName + URL . The exception was: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.  Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.0x80004005
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.AddInternal(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters param)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.SiteProvisioning.SiteProvisioningManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32().

Not sure if we are missing any dependency feature or missing any permission.  We have ensured that all services and service applications are running fine. The UPS services is syncing all users as well correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you created the MySite host on root of your MySite web application? Also did you created mySite wild card which you are using?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP
Yes, i did create a wildcard and the mysite host root on my mysite web application

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot as follows:

1.Make sure you have enable self-service site creation for the web application.

2.Ensure you have access to the My Site web application.

Please refer to the following article to configure it step by step:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/configure-my-sites

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/configure-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2016-step-by-step.html

Comment: Self-service site creation for the web app is enabled, i can access my site web app and with full control access
Every single step from this article was followed 
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/configure-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2016-step-by-step.html